# service fabric failed to contact the server. please try again later or get help from "how to configure secure connections"

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to deploy a service fabric application to an unsecure Azure Service Fabric cluster.  When I open the publish window in VS 2017 I get the following.  If my cluster is unsecure, shouldn't I be able to publish it w/o configuring the cert?

[image: vs error]

I tried a publish anyways and I got:

[image: publish errors]

[image: azure portal for service fabric cluster]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the server [via powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/connect-servicefabriccluster?view=azureservicefabricps) to maybe get a better error. Usually, errors like this are caused by firewalls blocking the port 19000.

Comment: I see, thanks Alex.  I tried that and I same error I got in the VS output window.  I've updated my question.  And now I see the message about connectivity/firewall/dns, thanks!

Comment: It was the firewall.  The network people opened up 19000 and it worked!

Comment: Is this firewall blocking at client side or azure side ?